# Which is more performant in single key and multiple key partitioning athena?

Tags: amazon-s3, hive, partition, amazon-athena, presto

When making queries in athena, which syntax is better, and why? Or does it matter at all?

- Simple partitioning by date: `s3: //example/2018-01-01` or
- multiple partition per year month day: `s3://example/2018/01/01`

Answer (score 0):

You can decide which partition will be more efficient only when you know what information you are looking for. Multiple partitions are used when the data stored is too large to reside in a single partition. Using more than one column for the partition key breaks the data into chunks or buckets. The data is still grouped but in smaller chunks. This method can be effective if a cluster experiences hot-spotting or congestion in writing data to one node repeatedly because a partition is heavily writing.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on lots of things .. your data volume per day, per month etc. Too many small files not good for Athena. Also how you are querying your data is important. Please look at the AWS article below for more idea.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/top-10-performance-tuning-tips-for-amazon-athena/